# Is it OK to have data lines and AC in the same multicore cable?

Tags: arduino, power, serial, ac, communication

I need to provide the following over sections of 1m multicore cable, totaling around 15m.

- 240v AC
- 5v DC
- GND
- RX
- TX

Will the AC cause problems for the Serial data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Operator safety and risks due to insulation failure are the primary concerns to address before even delving into the electronic side of the question.

Keeping the above aside, the answer would depend on the current passing through the power cables.

If the amount of current is large enough, the resultant electromagnetic interference on the other cables in the core would have severe detrimental effect.

This is easiest to visualize if you consider the way a clamp-type current meter operates - a signal is induced in the clamp's coil proportionate to the current flowing through the cable under test.

For moderate power supply currents, there exist special-purpose multicore cables specifically for the purpose described, such as [Ambicore Cable](http://www.rapidonline.com/audio-visual/van-damme-ambicore-power-and-signal-multicore-cable-10-amp-100m-02-3076):

[image: Ambicore Cable]

Note that such cables have a separate insulation for the power conductors as a group, and that the signal conductors are typically shielded to protect signal integrity.

Comment: That kind of cable seems ideal. I wounder if I should perhaps remove the need for +5v, and instead find some small pcb mounted psu.

Comment: @davivid You can find Ambicore type cables with the power bundle containing L-N-E conductors  and the shielded bundle containing 4 signal conductors. Alternatively, you could use an isolated 5 Volt DC switching regulator module, similar to what goes into mini travel chargers for cellphones, on the remote side, fed from the mains power you are sending across anyway. Do not use the signal shield as signal ground, leave it open on the remote end, and connect it to chassis ground on the master end.

Comment: Found one: http://www.directcablesystems.com/site/product_details.php?section_id=5&sub_section_id=370&category_id=5

Comment: @davivid There you go, problem solved.

Comment: @Anindo Ghosh - One quick thing, say I have 10 nodes in a chain, each connected by 1m lengths of this cable. How would I ground the signal shield? pass it through along with the others, and just connect to chassis ground on the master. Or could I just ground to Earth in each node - wouldn't this have the same effect?

Comment: @davivid I'm not the best person to answer that... I wouldn't even consider putting them in a chain, honestly: I prefer a star topology. I would suggest that this be asked as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, and it is likely to pose problems for the 5V. Capacitive coupling between cores is the 1st issue. Inductive coupling is the 2nd issue. However, if your multicore cable dimensions are large enough then maybe not. There is also the issue of user safety to consider.